# Adding an Integer to a float not working as expected

Tags: c

I know the following will not print 2.9 or 3. I can correct it but really want to understand what is internally happening so  it is printing:

> 858993459

How does this number come ?

I am running this under windows 32 bit

```
int main()
{
    double f = 1.9; 
    int t = 1;

    printf("%d\n", t+f); 

    return 0; 
}
```

**Update**

Simply believing that this would be "undefined behavior" was not possible for me, so I thought of investigating it further.  I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27621810/c-adding-an-integer-to-a-float/27621954#27621954) exactly what I wanted to understand.

Comment: t+f will result in a double, not an int then %d prints _garbage_.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti  What is the definition of garbage ? Also I wanted to understand exactly how that number is coming.

Comment: `printf` expects an integer and prints whatever you hand it over. If the argument is not what it expects, the behavior is undefined; it can do *anything*.

Comment: Whoever  downvoted. This is a valid question. I wanted to understand why those numbers are coming. There has to be reason those numbers are coming.  As can be seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27621810/c-adding-an-integer-to-a-float/27621954#27621954) there is a logical answer,  though with some assumptions. Also I did not find any other suitable forum where this could be asked.

Comment: You prolly got downvoted because of the high number of almost-dupes of this question - supplying printf with incorrect format specifiers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have already mentioned, this is undefined behaviour. But by taking some **assumptions** about the machine architecture, one can answer *why* it is printing these numbers:

Using [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) 64-bit format to represent doubles values, the value of `2.9` is the a stored as `0x4007333333333333`.

In a Little-Endian machine, the `%d` specifier will read the lower 4 bytes of that value, which are `0x33333333`, which equals `858.993.459`

Comment: Thanks. I think you are very close to what I was looking for. BTW How did you get 0x4007333333333333

Comment: Fine I used [this calculator](http://gregstoll.dyndns.org/~gregstoll/floattohex/)  to get this value

Answer (score 4):

you're using wrong format specifier. use `%f` instead.

As per the implicit type promotion rule, while doing `t+f`, `t` will be promoted to `double`. You're trying to print a `double` value using `%d`, which is supposed to expect an `int`.

Note: While using wrong format specifier, the behaviour is undefined.

**Related reading:** `c99` standard, chapter 7.19.6.1, paragraph 9, (emphasis mine)

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined. ***If any argument is
>   not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
>   undefined.***

Comment: I know but I want to know why the values are coming like that ?

Comment: @user3891236 while using wrong format specifier, the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: @user3891236 When you use the wrong specifier, the bits which represent the double are interpreted as if they would represent an integer, which is false

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh What is "undefined behavior" for windows ? Is it not documented anywhere? Is this something happen randomly ? If so if run this code tomorrow, it should give me a different result. Right?

Comment: @user3891236 how can something called _undefined behaviour_ be documented? if you're looking for a definition of undefined behaviour itself, see the [wiki entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: @user3891236: Undefined behavior is undefined. That means it's hard to say what will happen. It may vary depending on a lot of things, including the OS, the compiler, the compiler options, the hardware, or the moon phase. If it's undefined behavior, just don't go there.

Comment: @SouravGhosh If we can assume about the underlying architecture, then can't we predict the "undefined behavior" ?

Comment: @user3891236 mark my words carefully.. we ___can___ predict the undefined behaviour, but we ___cannot___ predict the outcome of undefined behaviour. Hope you're clear now. :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27621810/c-adding-an-integer-to-a-float/27621954#27621954)

Comment: @user3891236 make a note of the use ___assumption___. also note the update in my answer.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Don't think I donwvoted. I did not :-). But Why was my question downvoted?

Comment: @user3891236 don't worry, i know. it needs `125`. :-) would have been happier if the downvoter would bother to leave a comment though. regarding your question, maybe _people_ thought it's not _useful_.

Answer (score 4):

What happened is you try print a `double` using `%d`, so `printf` interpret this how an `integer`, but for you understand why this printed value, you have to understand how a `double` is stored by C language, C uses the `IEEE 754 standard`:

[image]

So `%d` interpret this as integer, and when you add an int and an double C keep this as `double` to not lose any part, and the result is a `double`, and `%d` interpret this sum as a `integer`, and like the format is different you see garbage.

you should use `%f` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to add integer and double so according to the thumb rule(type promotion rule) i.e. while this addition happens the integer will be promoted to double and the summation will happen and you are trying to print double value using `%d` format specifier which will lead to undefined behavior.

Use `%f` instead

PS: Using a wrong format specifer to print the value will lead to undefined behavior that is what you are seeing here.

Answer (score -1):

`%d` will transfer `double` to `int`

```
double f = 1.9; 
printf("%d\n", f);
```

Outputs:

> 1717986918

Computers store `int`s and `double`s in different ways, you can see it here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format